# Fluent configuration of multiple registrations

Tags: c#, autofac

I have two objects that should be registered together, and also share the same lifetime scoping.  I would like to provide a registration extension to encapsulate this and retain the registration fluency, but I need some help. Here's the situation I'm in:

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<?, ?, ?> 
  RegisterChannel<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder, Func<IComponentContext, ChannelFactory<T>> @delegate)
{
  // channelfactory and sharedchannel should have same lifetime configuration
  var channelfactoryreg = builder.Register(c => @delegate(c));
  var sharereg = builder.RegisterType<Wcf.SharedChannel<T>>();

  // is it possible to combine them and return?
  return ???;
}
```

How do I fill in the blanks so that I can write (e.g.) `builder.RegisterTwo().SingleInstance()`?  Is it possible to directly or indirectly "union" two `IRegistrationBuilderTLAR` objects, so that configuring the result configures all the underlying registrations, or is there another way to do this?

More generally: is there a primer out there for working with the Autofac internals?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Good question ... best I can think of, if you want to retain the basic syntax, is to implement `IRegistrationBuilder<object, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>` IIRC this is the lowest common denominator of these two types. Not sure how easy that is, admittedly Autofac's approach to building a fluent UI has some drawbacks :)

Comment: Zoiks. Okay then, I'm not married to the fluent syntax.  In my case I think it would suffice to extend with a method that takes an `Action<IRegistrationBuilder<L,A,R>>` delegate then apply the supplied delegate across the registrations within the extension method.  Any drawbacks you see there?  Am I violating any Autofac semantics?  I can imagine repeating this across every method of IRegistrationBuilder<...>, but the cost-benefit ratio doesn't make sense for me right now.  If it was part of Autofac, maybe... would such an implementation be a candidate for the core?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt: Oh, BTW: `builder.RegisterType<>()` returns `IRegistrationBuilder<TImplementor, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>`, so the 'LCD' of the two registrations is `IRegistrationBuilder<object, Autofac.Builder.IConcreteActivatorData, Autofac.Builder.SingleRegistrationStyle>`.  Don't know if that makes it any harder/easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, I hate answering my own Q, but all suggested alternatives seemed off-point or too complicated. Nick's comment came the closest to engaging, but only succeeded in scaring me off Autofac internals entirely ;).  I investigated, but that was overkill for my situation.

I ended up splitting the difference (as implied in my comment above), abandoning the fluent interface, but still allowing for flexible continuation of the registration by accepting the config into the method itself:

```
    public static void RegisterSharedChannel<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder, Func<IComponentContext, ChannelFactory<T>> @delegate, 
        Action<Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder<object, Autofac.Builder.IConcreteActivatorData, Autofac.Builder.SingleRegistrationStyle>> config)
    {
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<Wcf.ISharedChannel<T>>().GetChannel()).ExternallyOwned();
        //would be really nice to be able to retain the fluency of the interface, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608415/fluent-configuration-of-multiple-registrations
        //this should suffice for now...
        var facreg = builder.Register(c => @delegate(c));
        var sharereg = builder.RegisterType<Wcf.SharedChannel<T>>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        config(facreg);
        config(sharereg);
    }
```

The calling syntax isn't as pretty (e.g.:

```
builder.RegisterSharedChannel(c => BuildChannelFactory(...), r => r.SingleInstance());
```

but all (most of?) the flexibility is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a module to encapsulate registrations that make sense together.

IMHO, you should call `.SingleInstance()` in both registration. If they are two services they should be configured twice. If they share more commonalities in registration, you could register them with [Assembly Scanning](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning).

Comment: By the docs, modules seem more for shaping XML config (which I do not use). You'd need to make the case why they're more apropos than custom ContainerBuilder extensions.  Scanning is not a bad idea, but will not work if registration for one or both components becomes more complex (a delegate).  Perhaps I over-simplified my example, I will edit and update.

Comment: I think you've misread the docs, have a look at http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules#Common_Use_Cases_for_Modules

Answer (score 0):

I find that I make increasing use of the [IRegistrationSource](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/) interface for grouping together any related registrations. In your case, they would enable you to use the same registration code for an arbitrary set of types:

```
public class MyRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the registrations provided by this source are 1:1 adapters on top
    /// of other components (I.e. like Meta, Func or Owned.)
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve registrations for an unregistered service, to be used
    /// by the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">The service that was requested.</param>
    /// <param name="registrationAccessor">A function that will return existing registrations for a service.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Registrations providing the service.
    /// </returns>
    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (swt != null)
        {
            // Register requested service types that pass some test or other
            if (swt.ServiceType.HasAttribute<SomeAttribute>(true) ||
                typeof(SomeType).IsAssignableFrom(swt.ServiceType))
            {
                var registration = RegistrationBuilder.ForType(swt.ServiceType)
                    .InstancePerDependency()
                    .CreateRegistration();
                yield return registration;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little too far down the rabbit-hole for me, though an interesting read.